# 2sxc : Rename App Folder

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

How to rename app folder the right way?

For now, I try this way and don't know it this is OK

- export app
- edit content of the zip (rename folder / rename folder name in app.xml)
- delete app
- import changed app

This is maybe OK for test and development but is there any way for doing this in live site? (without loosing old content?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple :)

1. Rename the folder in the 2sxc
2. Update the folder name in the app-configuration (where you also have the app version etc.)

That's actually it already - no more magic to it :).

One thing that could still end up causing trouble is if your scripts have the folder name hard-wired (like /portals/0/2sxc/abc) instead of using @App.Path