# 2sxc - copy app to new folder and name

Tags: 2sxc

I created my "base" app which I plan to use for a different little-changed app with different views and additional fields.

What is the right and easiest way to make a copy of this base app to different name and folder?

Also can than that apps work side by side on one portal?

=== edit 1 ===

I already try to rename app like in this post: [2sxc : Rename App Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093107/2sxc-rename-app-folder)

Then create a new export of entire app, and restore portal to version before rename and try to import this "new" renamed app. But get the error...

Now I am looking to exported **App.xml** and there are "**EntityGUID**" and "**AttributeSet StaticName**" and "**App Guid**" with GUID values and I think that this is a problem at importing this "new" app...

Is it possible that I make a tool to parse this XML find all GUID-s then generated the same number of new GUID-s and replace old ones with new ones and repack ZIP and then try to import this? Can this be a solution or this is totally wrong?

Comment: I just created "edit 1" with what I already did and what I am thinking about next

Comment: I just finished version 1 of the app : https://github.com/pircjernej/NajdiNET.2sxc.Rename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make an app : https://github.com/pircjernej/NajdiNET.2sxc.Rename

If you build it or download exe from the release you can change Exported app ZIP file to new name and folder... Then just install this changed zip and do what you want...

Now work for my sample 2sxc app but did not test how to work with 2sxc sample apps... I will do this in next days...

If someone wants to test it help or contribute, you are welcome.

==== edit 1 =====

I make quick test with 2sxc blog app and I think that work OK